# Return a random selection from a string using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I would like a suggestion on why my code isnt working. The idea is to select only three names from a the list of names randomly, but it can't return the same name twice. I think it is close but I'm missing something here. Any help would be appreciated

```
(function(){

  var randomNames = function(){
      var names = ["Jeffrey, Ronald, Superman, Lyndon, Alison"];
      var myNames = [];

      for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++){
          var newNames = Math.floor(Math.random() * names.length);
          var randomAllNames = names[newNames];
          names.splice(newNames, 1);
          myNames.push(names);
          console.log(myNames);
      }
         return randomAllNames;

  }; randomNames();
})();
```

Comment: Your array contains only one element - a list of names - rather than an element per name.

Comment: also you are adding the entire array of names into the myNames array each loop iteration

Answer (score 1):

note the `myNames.push(randomAllNames);` also your array was just one long string

```
(function(){

  var randomNames = function(){
      var names = ["Jeffrey", "Ronald", "Superman", "Lyndon", "Alison"];
      var myNames = [];

      for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++){
          var newNames = Math.floor(Math.random() * names.length);
          var randomAllNames = names[newNames];
          names.splice(newNames, 1);
          myNames.push(randomAllNames);
          console.log(myNames);
      }
         return randomAllNames;

  }; randomNames();
})();
```

Comment: Ahhh, dumb mistake!! When I console.log(myNames); it returns 3 separate arrays. Amy I returning the wrong variable?       ["Alison"] main.js:19
["Alison", "Ronald"] main.js:19
["Alison", "Ronald", "Superman"]

Comment: yes, the inner function should return `myNames` and the last line should also be `return randomNames()` if you want to be able to use the result elsewhere

Comment: Yes, as I will be using the results to add to the HTML on the page. Each random name will appear in as a list item